# Google login through native webview or browser and not through app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I have integrated google signin in my app. The sign in is perfectly working with webview. But when I run the app on device,the google app is opening and after signed in no data is getting fetched. So my question is, how to solve this error or how to stop opening the google app when I click on signin button.

Note : I don't want to uninstall g+ app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply throw away Google+ Sign In SDK and work with the API manually.

In simple steps:

- Open Google+ Auth URL (like `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` plus attributes) in Safari / Webview / Safari View Controller
- process callback on provided callback URL with response data via `-application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` in your App delegate
- parse Auth code (as `code` attribute) from this URL
- call Google Auth API again by posting this code (URL like `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`) to obtain Auth token
- use this token for authentication the way you do right now

I realised this flow by reverse-engineering the Google+ library after seeing Google+ library to heavyweight and not effective especially because of some issues with it. You can additionally handle Google+ app this way as well, it's just differs in the initial URL you open.

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: I don't think you can fool the SDK itself. This is IMO one of the easiest alternatives.